# Unable to run a job in datalab

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

I would like to run a job in datalab using this code :

```
stepOneResult  = bq.Query(pagesEvents).execute(table_name=tableName, table_mode='create', use_cache=True, priority='interactive', allow_large_results=True)
```

I get this error when running the code :

```
     79       except Exception as e:
---> 80         raise e
     81       if query_result['jobComplete']:
     82         if 'totalBytesProcessed' in query_result:

RequestException: Not found: Job applied-arcanum-861:job_jLcsPiRqwcWiL4X1oTVnA-GKBgk
```

Any ideas on what is going on here or how to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try catching the exception and inspecting it.  There is a 'content' field that should have more info.

Is the target table in a different project?

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is the value of 'content' field : `Exception: {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "notFound",
    "message": "Not found: Job applied-arcanum-861:job__ISkcXVBgWvAVruWwAA2YA9gRYw"
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "Not found: Job applied-arcanum-861:job__ISkcXVBgWvAVruWwAA2YA9gRYw"
 }
}`   ... we don't have more information about the error.

Comment: I think you may be targeting a table in a different project and have hit this issue: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/datalab/issues/721

Comment: Yes, I make a query from another project and I'm trying to create a table in a different project like what we can do in BigQuery Web UI. When I make a query without trying create a table with query results, my query works well : `pagesEventsFrame = bq.Query(pagesEvents).to_dataframe()
pagesEventsFrame[:5]` .